# How to create a custom pipeline function in H2O?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, h2o

I am working on an Isolation Forests model in H2O that is saved as MOJO in order to run in an Android app. So far so good.

However I have some data preparation code that has to be run before this model - such as transform GPS coordinates into a known location, and provide the Isolation Forests model this location instead of the GPS coordinates. And it needs to be encapsulated in a MOJO as well (could be the same MOJO or a different one).

I thought about creating a custom pipeline function in H2O that could be saved as a MOJO as well, but I don't know if it's possible. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't possible at that moment. After talking to some representatives of H2O and reviewing my options, I ended up doing the data preparation in Android code and then just feeding the prepared data into the model.